# Connecting iphone with external device through bluetooth or wired connection

Tags: objective-c, iphone, external-accessory, mfi, ios-bluetooth

I have an external device that we need to connect with iPhone by using either Bluetooth or wired connection.

For connecting with Bluetooth we know that if the device has BLE then we can directly communicate with it Using CoreBluetooth Framework.
Otherwise we have to go to get it MFI registered.

Also if we want it to connect it using wired connection then also we have to get it MFI registered.But we have found a [cable](http://redpark.com/services/enterprise/) that connects device with iphone and that cable is MFI registerd. So if i use this cable for connecting iphone to device still do i need to get my device MFI registered??

For configuring this device initially i use desktop (putty). Through LAN cable i insert one end lan cable in device and second end in my computer, then using (putty) serial communication (through COM port) we send some commands to configure it. So, can this be done through iphone also if the device gets connected to iphone through usb cable??if Yes then how???if yes through bluetooth then how??

Answer (score 0):

From the developer of that cable's website

"MFI Certified

All Redpark cables are licensed through Apple’s “Made for iPod” (MFI) program and have earned MFI certification.

Apps developed with our SDK can be deployed under your **Apple Enterprise Developers license** with no further review or approval from Apple."

Key here is Apple Enterprise Developers license. If you're developing this application for internal release within your company it seems you don't need MFI. To be released on the app store I believe you would still need MFI.

As far as I know to configure your device from the phone rather than through your desktop would require a jailbroken phone. See here for a little info http://www.computerworld.com.au/slideshow/365979/great-iphone-serial-port-hack/?fp=4&fpid=5